# How to display html from a mysql database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, tags

I'm stuck with trying to figure out how to display html tags inside of a mysql table. I've tried using addslashes, mysql_real_escape_string, as well as stripslashes to view the tags properly. Everytime I view the data through the browser, it shows the text of the html. Example:

I have this in a mysql database table:

```
<strong>Test</strong>
```

It should display as this when viewed on a webpage:
**Test**

But instead, it displays `<strong>Test</strong>`

My PHP code to view the content is:

```
<?php

require_once("inc.php"); //This includes the configuration for mysql database

?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(NAME) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM events";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  echo(stripslashes($row['details'])); //The details is what contains the <strong>Test</strong>
}

mysql_close($conn) or die(mysql_error());

?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What code are you using to display the data? Also, based on your question, you should probably add PHP as a tag.

Comment: Most likely the framework you use does automatic output escaping to prevent xss attacks. In all the frameworks I know there is an easy way to output a string without escaping. You should add the name of your framework to the question.

Comment: I'm using PHP to display the data.

Answer (score 47):

Use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Replace the following line

```
  echo(stripslashes($row['details'])); //The details is what contains the <strong>Test</strong>
```

With

```
  echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['details'])); //The details is what contains the <strong>Test</strong>
```

Comment: This is working! why not accepted this answer. 
Really helpful.